# add virtual network to container from systemd nspawn

Tags: linux, systemd

i have virtual machine ubuntu 22.04. Network interface this vm is in bridge mode. inside this vm I have created buster container (debian) and edited it's unit file i added --network-ipvlan=enp0s3. I reloaded unit but still have no network on container.

network of host machine ubuntu 22.04

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2a:7c:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.229/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
       valid_lft 86357sec preferred_lft 86357sec
    inet6 fe80::c554:efd5:c2ca:824b/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

network of container buster

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: iv-enp0s3@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:2a:7c:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I have similar problems, but cannot find information that helps me out...